# Jetpack Compose Why Material Component Defaults Return State Type?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Material 3 `TextFieldDefaults` file contains the method below. The question is why this and similar methods's return type is `State<Color>` ? I've tried it in my code as return type `Color` without state is working as well. When the focus or other parameters change recomposition happens and new color returns with no problem. Therefore, I am curious about why it's return type `State<Color>` instead of `Color` what is the purpose of it, can you explain it with code examples if you can? (Like if you use Color instead of State you cannot do that.)

```
@Composable
internal fun placeholderColor(
    enabled: Boolean,
    isError: Boolean,
    interactionSource: InteractionSource
): State<Color> {
    val focused by interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()

    val targetValue = when {
        !enabled -> disabledPlaceholderColor
        isError -> errorPlaceholderColor
        focused -> focusedPlaceholderColor
        else -> unfocusedPlaceholderColor
    }
    return rememberUpdatedState(targetValue)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, of course color will change when the focus changed because it's tied to interactionSource state. The thing is, without returning state you can not react to color changes. If you want to observe what State does here, you should try to react to color changes instead of looking for whether the color is changed or not.